# 調べました versus 調べてわかりました

Tags: meaning, nuances

Regarding a new born panda:

> 東京の上野動物園は、１２日に生まれたパンダの赤ちゃんは女の子だと発表しました。
>   Tokyo's Ueno zoo announced that the baby panda born on the 12th is a girl.
>   ２２日の朝、中国の専門家と一緒に赤ちゃんの体を調べて**わかりました**。
>   On the morning of the 22nd (the zoo) together with Chinese experts examined the baby's body.

What is the purpose of adding 分かりました to the end of this sentence? How does the nuance change if you omit this verb?

Comment: その文のすぐ前に、何が分かったか書いてあると思いますので、直前の文を教えてもらえますか。

Comment: @Chocolate I added the previous sentence. After your comment I'm guessing that わかりました refers to determining the panda's sex?

Comment: Ohh yes, so they found out that the baby panda is a girl :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ２２日の朝、中国の専門家と一緒に赤ちゃんの体を調べて**わかりました**。

On the morning of the 22nd (the zoo) together with Chinese experts examined the baby's body and **found/figured it out**.

What they found/figured out must be mentioned in the sentence right before this.

Answer (score 2):

わかりました means "found out" or "learned"

調べてわかりました means "examined and found out", that is, "found out by examining"

So the sentence means "We found this out by examining the baby's body together with Chinese experts on the morning of the 22nd". The preceding sentence in the text tells us that Ueno Zoo has announced that the baby panda born on the 12th was female. Pandas are probably very protective of their newborn infants, so it was ten days before the zoo people could get a proper look at the infant.